# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error while finding convolution of images in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv. I am trying to do convolution of an image using kernel having same size as image in opencv c++. I am getting an error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. I checked for intialisation of variables and for loop. But I am not able to sort out exactly where the problem is coming. Can anybody please help me in finding out the problem. My code is given below:

```
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<cv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img;
Mat kernel, gd, dest;
int c = 120;
double mysum = 0.0, mysum1 = 0.0, k = 0;
int cent=0,radius=0;
enum ConvolutionType {   
    /* Return the full convolution, including border */
    CONVOLUTION_FULL, 

    /* Return only the part that corresponds to the original image */
    CONVOLUTION_SAME,

    /* Return only the submatrix containing elements that were not influenced by the       
    border       
    */
    CONVOLUTION_VALID
};

void conv2(const Mat &img, const Mat& kernel, ConvolutionType type,Mat& dest)
{

    Mat source = img;
    if(CONVOLUTION_FULL == type) 
    {
        source = Mat();
        const int additionalRows = kernel.rows - 1, additionalCols = kernel.cols - 1;
        copyMakeBorder(img, source, (additionalRows + 1) / 2, additionalRows / 2, 
            (additionalCols + 1) / 2, additionalCols / 2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
    }

    flip(kernel, kernel, -1);
    Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols / 2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows / 2 - 1);
    int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;
    filter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), kernel, anchor, 0, borderMode);

    if(CONVOLUTION_VALID == type)
    {
        dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols - 1) / 2, dest.cols - kernel.cols / 2).rowRange((kernel.rows - 1) / 2, dest.rows - kernel.rows / 2);
    }
} 

int main()
{  
    img = imread("building1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    dest.create(img.size(), img.type());
    gd.create(img.size(), img.type());

    for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
        {
            radius = ((cent - i)^2 + (cent - j)^2);
            gd.at<float>(j, i) = exp((-(radius) / c^2));

            mysum = mysum + gd.at<float>(j, i);
        }
        mysum1 = mysum1 + mysum; 
    }

    k=1/mysum1;
    cout<<endl<<k<<"\n"<<endl;

    for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
        {
            gd.at<float>(j, i) = k * gd.at<float>(j, i);
        }
    }  

    conv2(img, gd, CONVOLUTION_FULL, dest);
    imshow("conv", dest);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: horribly formatted code ;(

Comment: btw, a^b is a xor b , not pow(a,b)

Comment: Have you checked at what point this error comes? A simple way to find this out is comment out major portions of your code and see if the error persists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestions sir.I sort out where the problem is occuring.It is in this line:                            gd.at<float>(j, i) = exp((-(radius) / c^2));                        I think gd.at<float>(j, i) is going out of the bounds. Can you plz give me some suggestions to fix it.

Comment: I corrected C^2 by C*C . But again the same problem is showing.

Answer (score 1):

When you create `img`

```
img = imread("building1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

it will of type CV_UC3, i.e 3 bytes per pixel (one each for blue, green and red).

However when you access the image

```
gd.at<float>(j, i) = k * gd.at<float>(j, i);
```

you are using a float pointer. Since a float is 4 bytes, rather than 3, you will end up accessing memory outside of the image, or even your program. The latter is happening, as indicated by the segmentation violation.

Probably the best thing to do would be to compile your code in debug mode. THen you will probably get an exception from OpenCV rather than the segmentation violation.

It looks like what you might have wanted is

```
img = imread("building1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1); 
...
```

Also some of you code can be greatly simplified, e.g.

```
for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        gd.at<float>(j, i) = k * gd.at<float>(j, i);
    }
}
```

should be

```
gd = gd * k;
```

If you are accessing pixels sequentially the using `at<>()` is very inefficient. See [the efficient way](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. I tried with that ,again the same error is showing.

Comment: @user2943871 Don't say thank you - accept and upvote the answer! (assuming you want help next time :)